# What is the meaning of this Queue Property (iOS Audio Queues)?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueue

I want to write a player to play the music. I see the code like below:

```
AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(audioFile,
                         kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &size, nil);

if (size > 0) {
    cookie = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile,
                         kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &size, cookie);
    AudioQueueSetProperty(aduioQueue,
                          kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, cookie, size);
    free(cookie);
}
```

i don't know why to set the AudioQueueProperty,and what is the means about kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie? I can't find the help from the documentation.
who can give a direction to slove the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "magic cookie" is a file type signature consisting of a unique sequence of bytes at the beginning of the file, indicating the file format.  The audio queue framework uses this information to determine how to decode or extract audio information from a file stream (instead of using or trusting the file name extension).  The code you posted reads this set of bytes from the file, and passes it to the audio queue as a cookie. (It would be a mistake to let them be interpreted as PCM samples instead, for instance).

Comment: thanks your help. I find the documentation about the kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie. It says that : "If the audio format you are playing or recording to requires a magic cookie, you must set a value for this property before enqueuing any buffers."... In my app, I clear the code above , the sound is OK. My question is that the audio queue has the ability to estimate file format?

Answer (score 2):

Actually magic cookie is more than just a signature, it holds some information about the encoder, most useful items are "Maximum Bit Rate" and "Average Bit Rate", specially for a compressed format like AudioFileMPEG4Type. For this specific type magic cookie is same as "esds" box in MPEG-4 data file. You can find the exact bit settings at:

http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt

---

8+ bytes vers. 2 ES Descriptor box
                   = long unsigned offset + long ASCII text string 'esds'
                   - if encoded to ISO/IEC 14496-10 AVC standards then optionally use:
                      = long unsigned offset + long ASCII text string 'm4ds'

```
                -> 4 bytes version/flags = 8-bit hex version + 24-bit hex flags
                    (current = 0)

                -> 1 byte ES descriptor type tag = 8-bit hex value 0x03
                -> 3 bytes extended descriptor type tag string = 3 * 8-bit hex value
                  - types are Start = 0x80 ; End = 0xFE
                  - NOTE: the extended start tags may be left out
                -> 1 byte descriptor type length = 8-bit unsigned length

                  -> 2 bytes ES ID = 16-bit unsigned value
                  -> 1 byte stream priority = 8-bit unsigned value
                    - Defaults to 16 and ranges from 0 through to 31

                    -> 1 byte decoder config descriptor type tag = 8-bit hex value 0x04
                    -> 3 bytes extended descriptor type tag string = 3 * 8-bit hex value
                      - types are Start = 0x80 ; End = 0xFE
                      - NOTE: the extended start tags may be left out
                    -> 1 byte descriptor type length = 8-bit unsigned length

                      -> 1 byte object type ID = 8-bit unsigned value
                        - type IDs are system v1 = 1 ; system v2 = 2
                        - type IDs are MPEG-4 video = 32 ; MPEG-4 AVC SPS = 33
                        - type IDs are MPEG-4 AVC PPS = 34 ; MPEG-4 audio = 64
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 simple video = 96
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 main video = 97
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 SNR video = 98
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 spatial video = 99
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 high video = 100
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 4:2:2 video = 101
                        - type IDs are MPEG-4 ADTS main = 102
                        - type IDs are MPEG-4 ADTS Low Complexity = 103
                        - type IDs are MPEG-4 ADTS Scalable Sampling Rate = 104
                        - type IDs are MPEG-2 ADTS = 105 ; MPEG-1 video = 106
                        - type IDs are MPEG-1 ADTS = 107 ; JPEG video = 108
                        - type IDs are private audio = 192 ; private video = 208
                        - type IDs are 16-bit PCM LE audio = 224 ; vorbis audio = 225
                        - type IDs are dolby v3 (AC3) audio = 226 ; alaw audio = 227
                        - type IDs are mulaw audio = 228 ; G723 ADPCM audio = 229
                        - type IDs are 16-bit PCM Big Endian audio = 230
                        - type IDs are Y'CbCr 4:2:0 (YV12) video = 240 ; H264 video = 241
                        - type IDs are H263 video = 242 ; H261 video = 243
                      -> 6 bits stream type = 3/4 byte hex value
                        - type IDs are object descript. = 1 ; clock ref. = 2
                        - type IDs are scene descript. = 4 ; visual = 4
                        - type IDs are audio = 5 ; MPEG-7 = 6 ; IPMP = 7
                        - type IDs are OCI = 8 ; MPEG Java = 9
                        - type IDs are user private = 32
                      -> 1 bit upstream flag = 1/8 byte hex value
                      -> 1 bit reserved flag = 1/8 byte hex value set to 1
                      -> 3 bytes buffer size = 24-bit unsigned value
                      -> 4 bytes maximum bit rate = 32-bit unsigned value
                      -> 4 bytes average bit rate = 32-bit unsigned value

                        -> 1 byte decoder specific descriptor type tag
                            = 8-bit hex value 0x05
                        -> 3 bytes extended descriptor type tag string
                            = 3 * 8-bit hex value
                          - types are Start = 0x80 ; End = 0xFE
                          - NOTE: the extended start tags may be left out
                        -> 1 byte descriptor type length
                            = 8-bit unsigned length

                          -> ES header start codes = hex dump

                    -> 1 byte SL config descriptor type tag = 8-bit hex value 0x06
                    -> 3 bytes extended descriptor type tag string = 3 * 8-bit hex value
                      - types are Start = 0x80 ; End = 0xFE
                      - NOTE: the extended start tags may be left out
                    -> 1 byte descriptor type length = 8-bit unsigned length

                      -> 1 byte SL value = 8-bit hex value set to 0x02
```

"

Magic Cookie that comes from kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData starts from ES Descriptor (just ignore the first 4 bytes described in the map and rest will be an exact match to magick cookie).

A sample magic cookie would be like this:

```
03 80 80 80 22 00 00 00 04 80 80 80 14 40 15 00 18 00 00 00 FA 00 00 00 FA 00 05 80 80 80 02 12 08 06 80 80 80 01 02
```

Maximum bit rate is at offset 18 -> 0XFA00 (or 64,000)
Average bit rate is at offset 22 -> 0XFA00 (or 64,000)

Although according to Apple documentation, magic cookie is read/write, but I had no chance changing the bit rate before creating or converting files.

Hope that helps someone.